Azure Pipelines Deployment to static web app timing out suddenly
We use Azure pipelines to build and deploy our react app to Azure Static Web apps.
We use Microsoft Hosted agent(ubuntu-latest) to run our CI/CD pipeline.
From last two days, all of a sudden, our pipelines have started taking too long to perform the npm build steps.
The npm install and build task which used to take around 4-5 minutes to complete is now taking 20-25 minutes.
The same is with the AzureStaticWebApp@0 task which used to take 4-5 mins now takes more than 15-20 minutes and times out due to default timeout of 15 mins getting breached.
We have not made any changes to the code.
Why is this happening and how can we resolve this?
Both the tasks in questions are:
  - script: |
      npm install
      npm run build --prod --if-present
    displayName: 'npm install and build'


  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      app_location: '/'
      api_location: 'api'
      output_location: ''
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_UAT)
      skip_app_build: false
    displayName: 'Deploy to UAT Static Web App'

Update: Agent Details(same as old build runs on which these tasks were faster)


How long has this issue been happening? Even if there are no code changes, there are other variables to consider: new versions of the Azure pipeline tasks, SDKs or other tools installed into the build agent (Microsoft-hosted agents are typically updated weekly), network issues, Azure DevOps outages, etc.

It is happening since last two days. We are using ubuntu-latest and I have checked that our latest builds are running on the same Runner image as previous ones.
Please see the updated post screenshot.
